# I'm making a Dungeons and Dragons style game in python, but I'm getting incorrect if returns

Tags: python, class, random, python-2.7

I've worked out how to do most of this stuff in the past couple of days, but that's all the experience i have, so this is probably simple.
Anyway, everything was going fine, until I tried to complicate a few formula's, or at least change the values they used. Here is what I'm working with.

```
class EnemyStats():
    def Ename(self):
        return #Not sure What i should put in these spots...
    def EBaseDodge(self):
        return 
    def EnemyEvasion(self):
        return 
    def ENickRange(self):
        return 
    def EBaseAttack(self):
        return 
    def EWeaponAttack(self):
        return 
    def EAttackRating(self):
        return 
    def EnemyDefense(self):
        return 
    def EAttackDamage(self):
        return 
    def Damage(self):
        return ((PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense)if (PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense>0) else 0);
    def EDamage(self):
        return ((EAttackDamage-PDefense) if ((EAttackDamage-PDefense)>0) else 0);
    def LightAttackDamage(self):
        return int(LightAttackDamage == (Damage * 0.72));
    def HeavyAttackDamage(self):
        return (Damage * 1.28);
    def LightNicked(self):
        return (LightAttackDamage/2);
    def HeavyNicked(self):
        return (HeavyAttackDamage/2);
    def Nicked(self):
        return (Damage/2)

    def Estats(self):
        Ename = raw_input('Target Enemy Name: ');
        EBaseDodge = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Dodge: '));
        EnemyEvasion = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Evasion: '));
        ENickRange = (EBaseDodge + EnemyEvasion);
        EBaseAttack = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Base Attack: '));
        EWeaponAttack = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Weapon Attack(If N/A, 0): '));
        EAttackRating = (EBaseAttack + EWeaponAttack);
        EnemyDefense = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Defense: '));
        EAttackDamage = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Attack Damage: '));
        Damage = ((PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense)if (PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense>0) else 0);
        EDamage = ((EAttackDamage-PDefense) if ((EAttackDamage-PDefense)>0) else 0);
        LightAttackDamage = (Damage * 0.72);
        HeavyAttackDamage = (Damage * 1.28);
        LightNicked = (LightAttackDamage/2);
        HeavyNicked = (HeavyAttackDamage/2);
        Nicked = (Damage/2)
```

And then it is referenced by this.

```
def PLightAttackForm():#light attack
    print 'Light attack!';
    d = dice()
    lightbase = d.LightAttack()
    EE = EnemyStats()
    if lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge:
        print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Miss!', 0, 'Damage!'
    elif lightbase > EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Hit!', EE.LightAttackDamage, 'Damage!'
    elif lightbase < EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Nicked!', EE.LightNicked, 'Damage!'
    else:
        print lightbase
```

And Everything goes amazing, no errors, but i get this.

Light attack!
You rolled 700 , Miss! 0 Damage! #Should be a Hit and damage

Normal Attack!
You rolled 278 , Miss! 0 Damage! #should be hit and damage

Heavy Attack!
You rolled 135 , Miss! 0 Damage!#should be a Nick and damage

I'm sure it's just something i don't really know, But if you could help me out that would be amazing!
Thank you!

Also, here is all the code i have written. Might have some redundancy... :D

```
import random
Name = raw_input("Enter Name: ")
#EName===
#EBaseDodge = int(raw_input("Enter Enemy Dodge: "))
PBaseDodge = int(input('Enter Base Dodge: '))
#EnemyEvasion = int(raw_input("Enter Enemy Evasion: "))
PEvasion = int(input('Enter Evasion: '))
#ENickRange = (EBaseDodge + EnemyEvasion)
PNickRange = (PBaseDodge + PEvasion)
PBaseAttack = int(raw_input("Enter Base Attack: "))
#EBaseAttack===
PWeaponAttack = int(raw_input("Enter Weapon Attack: "))
#EWeaponAttack===
PAttackRating = (PBaseAttack + PWeaponAttack)
#EAttackRating = (EBaseAttack + EWeaponAttack)
#EnemyDefense = int(raw_input("Enter Enemy Defense: "))
PDefense = int(input('Enter Defense: '))
PAttackDamage = int(raw_input("Enter Attack Damage: "))
#EAttackDamage===
#Damage = (PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense)
#EDamage = (EAttackDamage-PDefense)
#LightAttackDamage = (Damage * 0.72)
#HeavyAttackDamage = (Damage * 1.28)
#LightNicked = (LightAttackDamage/2)
#HeavyNicked = (HeavyAttackDamage/2)
#Nicked = Damage/2


class dice():
        def NormalAttack(self):
            return random.randint(1, PAttackRating);
        def LightAttack(self):
            return random.randint(1, (int(PAttackRating*1.25)));
        def HeavyAttack(self):
            return random.randint(1, (int(PAttackRating*0.75)));


#def att():
#   d = dice()
#   base = d.roll()
#   if base <= a:
#       print 'You rolled', base, ', Miss!', 0, 'Damage!'
#   elif base > b:
#       print 'You rolled', base, ', Hit!', Damage, 'Damage!'
#   elif base < b:
#       print 'You rolled', base, ', Nicked!', Nicked, 'Damage!'
#   else:
#       print base

####################NEW CODE#######################################
def Menu():
    print '(1)Attack';
    print '(2)Choose Enemy';
    print '(3)Charge';
    print '(4)Item';


def select():
    choice = input('Enter Choice: ');
    EE = EnemyStats()
    if (choice == 1):
        Attacktype();
    elif (choice == 2):
        EE.Estats();
    elif (choice == 3):
        Charge();
    elif (choice == 4):
        ItemSelection();
    else:
        print 'There are Numbers for a reason Nuub!',;

##############Enemy Stats############

class EnemyStats():
    def Ename(self):
        return 
    def EBaseDodge(self):
        return 
    def EnemyEvasion(self):
        return 
    def ENickRange(self):
        return 
    def EBaseAttack(self):
        return 
    def EWeaponAttack(self):
        return 
    def EAttackRating(self):
        return 
    def EnemyDefense(self):
        return 
    def EAttackDamage(self):
        return 
    def Damage(self):
        return ((PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense)if (PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense>0) else 0);
    def EDamage(self):
        return ((EAttackDamage-PDefense) if ((EAttackDamage-PDefense)>0) else 0);
    def LightAttackDamage(self):
        return int(LightAttackDamage == (Damage * 0.72));
    def HeavyAttackDamage(self):
        return (Damage * 1.28);
    def LightNicked(self):
        return (LightAttackDamage/2);
    def HeavyNicked(self):
        return (HeavyAttackDamage/2);
    def Nicked(self):
        return (Damage/2)

    def Estats(self):
        Ename = raw_input('Target Enemy Name: ');
        EBaseDodge = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Dodge: '));
        EnemyEvasion = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Evasion: '));
        ENickRange = (EBaseDodge + EnemyEvasion);
        EBaseAttack = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Base Attack: '));
        EWeaponAttack = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Weapon Attack(If N/A, 0): '));
        EAttackRating = (EBaseAttack + EWeaponAttack);
        EnemyDefense = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Defense: '));
        EAttackDamage = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Attack Damage: '));
        Damage = ((PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense)if (PAttackDamage-EnemyDefense>0) else 0);
        EDamage = ((EAttackDamage-PDefense) if ((EAttackDamage-PDefense)>0) else 0);
        LightAttackDamage = (Damage * 0.72);
        HeavyAttackDamage = (Damage * 1.28);
        LightNicked = (LightAttackDamage/2);
        HeavyNicked = (HeavyAttackDamage/2);
        Nicked = (Damage/2)



#Attacking
def Attacktype():
    print '(1)LightAttack';
    print '(2)NormalAttack';
    print '(3)HeavyAttack';
    print '(4)Use Dem Magicks';
    print '(5)Menu(<<This is for nuublets)';
    Attchoice = input('Enter Choice: ')
    if (Attchoice == 1):
        PLightAttackForm();
    elif (Attchoice == 2):
        PNormalAttackForm();
    elif (Attchoice == 3):
        PHeavyAttackForm();
    elif (Attchoice == 4):
        MagicMenu();
    elif (Attchoice == 5):
        Menu();
    else:
        print 'You wot M8?';
        Menu();


def PLightAttackForm():#light attack
    print 'Light attack!';
    d = dice()
    lightbase = d.LightAttack()
    EE = EnemyStats()
    if lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge:
        print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Miss!', 0, 'Damage!'
    elif lightbase > EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Hit!', EE.LightAttackDamage, 'Damage!'
    elif lightbase < EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Nicked!', EE.LightNicked, 'Damage!'
    else:
        print lightbase

def PNormalAttackForm():#Normal attack
    print 'Normal Attack!';
    d = dice()
    base = d.NormalAttack()
    EE = EnemyStats()
    if base <= EE.EBaseDodge:
        print 'You rolled', base, ', Miss!', 0, 'Damage!'
    elif base > EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', base, ', Hit!', EE.Damage, 'Damage!'
    elif base < EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', base, ', Nicked!', EE.Nicked, 'Damage!'
    else:
        print base

def PHeavyAttackForm():#Heavy Attack
    print 'Heavy Attack!';
    d = dice()
    heavybase = d.HeavyAttack()
    EE = EnemyStats()
    if heavybase <= EE.EBaseDodge:
        print 'You rolled', heavybase, ', Miss!', 0, 'Damage!'
    elif heavybase > EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', heavybase, ', Hit!', EE.HeavyAttackDamage, 'Damage!'
    elif heavybase < EE.ENickRange:
        print 'You rolled', heavybase, ', Nicked!', EE.HeavyNicked, 'Damage!'
    else:
        print heavybase

def MagicMenu():#magic menu()   
    print 'Magic menu!';


##############Enemy Stats############



####################NEW CODE#######################################
```

Comment: You're not passing any parameters to your methods. I'm not sure how you're not getting errors.

Comment: I wish i was, That's how i learned even this much TT_TT

Comment: Just a hint on style.  Don't put semicolon at the end of lines. Don't enclose stuff in parens that don't need it.  Call your functions or make them properties.

Comment: Also, even if you fix this problem, I don't think your code will do what you want. For example, `LightAttackDamage` is defined as: `return int(LightAttackDamage == (Damage * 0.72));`. If you changed that to call the functions, `LightAttackDamage` will call itself, which will call itself, etc., until you get a recursion depth error. And then, once you fix that, you're comparing two values, which means you get either `True` or `False`, and then returning `int()` of that, which means `1` or `0`. I don't think that's what this function is intended to return, is it?

Comment: Also, I don't think you've gotten the point about classes. Usually, each instance of a class has some attributes created in the `__init__` method. You're trying to create the object, then set its attributes with an `Estats` method. While this "two-stage initialization" is sometimes appropriate, it's much less common, and more complicated. Plus, you've given your attributes the same names as your methods, which means the methods will be replaced by strings, and there will be no way to call the methods

Comment: No that was a noob failed fix. I just dropped in the formula for LightAttackDamage there.

Comment: @That1Guy My bad, forgot about that entirely :o Edited it out.

Comment: @abarnert No, Its my first language, and I cooked this up in about 4 hours. Most of that was unbreaking it. Still broken, but i'm working on it.

Comment: @HunterTracy: No problem. But you may want to either work farther through a tutorial, or try a much simpler toy example, before trying to get this working. I know, toy examples are boring… but writing hundreds of lines of code wrong and then having to change all of them is _also_ boring. Anyway, however you proceed, good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As That1Guy said, you're not passing parameters to your functions. In python, functions are objects as well, and you can compare them to other objects. So when you do:

```
if lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge:
    print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Miss!', 0, 'Damage!'
elif lightbase > EE.ENickRange:
    print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Hit!', EE.LightAttackDamage, 'Damage!'
elif lightbase < EE.ENickRange:
    print 'You rolled', lightbase, ', Nicked!', EE.LightNicked, 'Damage!'
else:
    print lightbase
```

`lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge` always evaluates to true.

You need to add parenthesis to the calls to`EBase...` methods. Also you need to add return values to the declaration of the methods. so make your functions look something like (assuming you have a variable called base_dodge):

```
 def EBaseDodge(self):
    return base_dodge
```

and change your ifs to:

```
 if lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge():
    ...
```

I'm not sure why you are trying to use methods for all of those values in the first place. It would make more sense if the methods were attributes.

Try removing all of the methods in `Enemystats` and making your variables instance variables:

```
class EnemyStats:
    def Estats(self):
        #Keep this method to set all of the stats and add self. before them like this
        self.Ename = raw_input('Target Enemy Name: ');
        self.EBaseDodge = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Dodge: '));
        self.EnemyEvasion = int(raw_input('Enter Enemy Evasion: '));
        self.ENickRange = (self.EBaseDodge + self.EnemyEvasion);
        ....
```

Putting `self.` before all of your variables associates them to an instance of your class (`EnemyStats`).

Then to create a new EnemyStats object and input the values:

```
EE = EnemyStats()
EE.Estats() # will prompt you for the values
```

After that you can reference your values like you had wanted to before:

```
if lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge:
   ...
```

Just so you know, this is not the most organized/recommended way of doing things.

Comment: Don't know who to reply to first! Thanks, That sent out a grip of errors! Now i can fix it XD.
Also thanks for the def-> return help!

Comment: @HunterTracy If this answer is correct, you should mark it as such to help future users identify their issues.

Comment: This isn't the whole story. Notice that `Estats` method? If he called that, it would replace the `EBaseDodge` method with a number. And I think that number is what he actually wants to compare to here.

Comment: @abarnert Yes it was, and sorry i wasn't clear. Thanks for that, And i will keep looking for how to work with classes. Now that i have errors, google can help me. Usually leads me to this forum to :D.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually call any of your class methods. You simply compare your value against the function object itself, which is not something you'd usually do. For instance, you should do:

```
if lightbase <= EE.EBaseDodge():
```

(note the parentheses) - of course, as soon as you do that, you'll get lots and lots of errors, as there are several other issues with this code.